# MS Project 2010 - Custom Duration summaries in hours

Tags: microsoft-project, microsoft-project-2010

I have a custom Duration field in MS Project 2010 that I want to display in hours. (I'm tracking work estimates.) For task lines, I can enter the value in hours (e.g. 8 hrs.) and it displays it that way.  On the custom field definition, I have set the summary values to be a sum of the task lines.  However, all the summary lines display the duration in days, not hours.  How can I get the summary lines to display in hours?

I've tried:

- Setting all the tasks under the summary to a number of hours.  The summary is still in days.
- Turning off the summation of summary lines, setting the summary lines to 0 hrs so that they display that way, then turning summation back on.  The summary lines then revert to days.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Duration display in Project is set through the option settings in File > Options.  That setting controls the display of all calculated durations and summary task lines are calculated.

You can use a spare text field (text1 for example) to display the entered values in hours.  Assuming you have the entered values in Duration 1:

```
            **Duration1/480*8 & " hours"**
```

I hope this helps.